# Call a constructor from variable arguments with PHP

Tags: php, constructor, callback

I have a function that takes variadic arguments, that I obtain from `func_get_args()`.

This function needs to call a constructor with those arguments. However, I don't know how to do it.

With `call_user_func`, you can call functions with an array of arguments, but how would you call a constructor from it? I can't just pass the array of arguments to it; it must believe I've called it "normally".

Thank you!

Comment: Since PHP 5.6 you can use _argument unpacking_: `new SomeClass( ... [ 'arg1', 'arg2' ] );`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For PHP < 5.3 it's not easily doable without first creating an instance of the class with `call_user_func_array`. However with [`Reflection`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) this is pretty trivial:

```
$reflection = new ReflectionClass( 'yourClassName' );
$instance = $reflection->newInstanceArgs( $yourArrayOfConstructorArguments );
```

Comment: Another feature of PHP 5.3 I wasn't aware of. Thanks, it's gonna do it.

Comment: Thank you for the example. This is probably the first thing in the PHP manual that I've found wasn't explained very well.

Comment: @zneak, `ReflectionClass::newInstanceArgs` is not new in PHP 5.3, we've had it around since 2006 when it was released with PHP 5.1.3.  @byronh, is there anything in particular that you found not well explained or are you referring to the parts labeled as "undocumented"? (Feel free to email me, salathe@php.net)

Comment: @salathe: +1 exactly. That was what I was trying to bring across.

Answer (score -2):

If for some reason you can not use `ReflectionClass::newInstanceArgs` here is another solution using eval():

```
function make_instance($class, $args) {
   $arglist = array();
   $i = 0; 
   foreach($args => &$v) {
       $arglist[] = $n = '_arg_'.$i++;
       $$n = &$v;
   }
   $arglist = '$'.implode(',$',$arglist);
   eval("\$obj = new $class($arglist);");
   return $obj;
}
$instance = make_instance('yourClassName', $yourArrayOfConstructorArguments);
```

Note that using this function enables you to pass arguments by reference to the constructor, which is not acceptable with `ReflectionClass::newInstanceArgs`.

Comment: What is wrong with this answer? Any comments?
Is it just because of `eval`? I've clearly stated at the beginning this is an alternative solution using `eval`