# Loop through dependencies array and inject them

Tags: php

I have an array, `$dependencies`, with all the dependency objects.

At the last line I'm returning the instantiated object.

How can I inject all the dependency objects I have in the array?

```
class IoC
{
    public static function make($object)
    {
        $class  = new ReflectionClass($object);
        $params = $class->getConstructor()->getParameters();

        foreach ($params as $param) {
            $dependency     = $param->getClass()->name;
            $dependencies[] = new $this->make($dependency);
        }

        $name = $class->getName();

        return new $name(); //todo
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making a recursive call for each of your dependencies.  Each dependency can itself have dependencies that need to be 'constructed':

```
foreach ($params as $param) {
    $dependency     = $param->getClass()->name;
    $dependencies[] = $this->make('dependency');
}
```

As far as passing them to the constructor of the object, don't rely on `new` here.  Instead, use reflection as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2640263/697370):

```
$reflection = new ReflectionClass( 'yourClassName' );
$instance = $reflection->newInstanceArgs( $dependencies );
```

In your case this would be:

```
return $class->newInstanceArgs($dependencies);
```